# VBA Returning Value as Less than when it is Equal to

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, time, boolean

I have a daily scheduling task program that seems to be bugging out specific times during the day.

I have a table with column A being a variable increment of time throughout the day (12:00 Am - 11:30 Pm in 30 minute increments (48 Rows)) and 7 Days of the week across 7 columns B-H.

I also have a list of activities that occur at some point during the day. This program simply fills in the time slot with the appropriate activity by checking if the time indicated in the row is greater than or equal to the beginning time of the activity and less than the end time and on that specific day.

A problem occurs when I reach 8 Am. There is task that should end up until 8 AM, meaning that rows from 12 AM to 7:30 AM should be filled and 8 Am row should be blank because of the condition >= start time and < end time. But this doesn't work. The boolean variable currenttimeVendnum says 0.33333333 < 0.33333333 is TRUE (0.33333333 is excels time value for 8 AM) which obviously isn't the case.

Is it because its repeating? I tried rounding it down to 5 digits but that didn't work. Any ideas? I tried some debugging as in the code.

Code is below:

```
Sub Schedule()


Dim timeIncrement As Range, ws As Worksheet, seperator As Integer, endRow As Integer, begRow As Integer, col As Integer, rw As Integer, begCol As Integer, endCol As Integer, lastRow As Integer
Dim currenttime As Double, begNum As Double, endNum As Double, tableRow As Double
Dim currentimeVbegnum As Boolean, currenttimeVendnum As Boolean


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily Planner")
Set timeIncrement = ws.Range("c1")

'time intervals in planner
seperator = timeIncrement.Value

'last row of predefined activities
lastRow = ws.Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'first day of planner (Sunday)
begCol = 2
'last day of week (Saturday)
endCol = begCol + 6
'first time in planner (12:00 AM)
begRow = 4
'last time in planner (11:30 PM)
endRow = 60 / seperator * 24 + begRow


ws.Range(Cells(begRow, begCol), Cells(endRow, endCol)).ClearContents

For rw = begRow To endRow
    On Error GoTo ExitLoop:
'   Debug.Assert (rw < 18)
    For col = begCol To endCol
    currenttime = ws.Cells(rw, 1).Value
        For tableRow = begRow To lastRow
            'If InStr(1, ws.Cells(tableRow, 10), "Sleep") And ws.Cells(tableRow, 12).Value > 0.5 Then
             '   If (InStr(1, ws.Cells(tableRow, 11), (col - 1))) And (currenttime < ws.Cells(tableRow, 14).Value Or currenttime >= ws.Cells(tableRow, 12).Value) And (ws.Cells(tableRow, 15).Value > 0) Then
                    'ws.Cells(rw, col) = ws.Cells(tableRow, 10)
              '  End If
            begNum = ws.Cells(tableRow, 12).Value
            endNum = ws.Cells(tableRow, 14).Value
            currentimeVbegnum = currenttime >= begNum
            currenttimeVendnum = currenttime < endNum
            If currenttime >= begNum And currenttime < endNum And InStr(1, ws.Cells(tableRow, 11), (col - 1)) And ws.Cells(tableRow, 15).Value > 0 Then
                ws.Cells(rw, col) = ws.Cells(tableRow, 10)
            End If
        Next tableRow
    Next col
Next rw
ExitLoop:
    Exit Sub


End Sub
```

Comment: Most likely floating point error, so yes you should round to some number of significant digits.

Comment: The worked for activities that went too long, But now some don't start when they should. Ex.) An activity that should start at 10 now starts at 10:30

Comment: Nevermind, I just only need to round the end time not begging time. Thanks Ben.

Comment: Since you are comparing doubles, you should always round both numbers.  Rounding only 1 may work in this case, but I doubt it will work in all cases.